# Django image not getting uploaded

Tags: python, django, image-uploading

We are making our school site on Django, we made a gallery app but i think the images are not getting uploaded to designated folder, rather they are not even getting uploaded i think so .
Code : -

```
# views.py
def upload(request, template_name="gallery/form.html"):
   form = GalleryForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
   if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
     messages.success(request, "image has been uploaded")
     return redirect('gallery.views.index')

   return render(request, template_name,{'form':form})

from django.db import models

# models.py
class GalleryPhoto(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pic_folder/')
   description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.image.url
```

The rest of the code can be seen in this [repo](https://github.com/Anurag-Ans/JHTS/tree/master/gallery) 
Note : the the gallery template contains some conflicts but that is not the actual problem.

Comment: There is conflicts in your https://github.com/Anurag-Ans/JHTS/blob/master/templates/gallery/index.html file . resolve it . and then try.

Comment: yeah, i had seen that and even after fixing it on my local machine , it was still not working :(

Comment: just forgot to push the code

Comment: POST data getting printed in `def upload` ?

Comment: I mean put some 'print' statements in `def upload` inside `views.py` to check u r getting posted at right url or not .

Comment: don't know about print statement but when i added a message -> messages.success(request, "image has been uploaded") 
then it was displayed successfully .

Comment: Why are you using `tempfile`?? It should be `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` or something similar

Comment: yuvi , thats for django-ckeditor, but even after changing to what you suggested, it was still not solved .

Comment: I just cloned your repository. With the changes I suggested, while the images are still not displayed correctly, at least I could verify that *they are being uploaded correctly*. I'll look into it further when I'll have the time

Comment: @yuvi did u get any answer ??

Comment: yes. I'll post shortly

Comment: There. it turns out MEDIA_ROOT doesn't matter here (though maybe don't point it at a temporary directory). Just make sure MEDIA_URL is configured correctly (it isn't). `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` should do it for development...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to notice it, because it's kinda tricky. But in retrospect it's obvious.

So after configuring `MEDIA_URL = "/MEDIA/"` I noticed that `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/` was giving me a 404. If everything is configured correctly (and it is) then usually the problem is conflicting urls. See the url patterns used in django are always evaluated in order. That means if you have urls like so:

```
url(r'^mypage/', 'myapp.mypage'),
url(r'^mypage/another/', 'myapp.different')
```

Then the second url *will never be available*. Why? because there's nothing up there that tells the url dispatcher that the first url should end at `mypage/`. As far as it's concerned, everything starting with `http://DOMAIN/mypage/` will be caught and passed to the first function.

To avoid that, we use the `$` sign to tell the dispatcher at what point to stop. Like so:

```
url(r'^mypage/$', 'myapp.mypage'),
url(r'^mypage/another/$', 'myapp.different')
```

Now let's look at your last two urls:

```
    url(r'^', include('pages.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

See that? `url(r'^'` swallows everything that comes after it, so no media is being served. It's true that `pages.urls` uses a dollar for its first url:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

but that doesn't matter for the main url dispatcher, which evaluates `r'^'` first. What's the solution? the simplest would be to move the `pages` urls to the end:

```
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^', include('pages.urls')))
```

You can also isolate that one problematic url from the others using a direct call, like so:

```
url(r'^/$', 'pages.views.index'),
url(r'^pages/$',  include('pages.urls')),
```

After that, this will work:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.image.url }}"  alt="{{ image.description }}">
```

**p.s.**

Eventually you're going to pass the media and static files through your server, when you move to deployment level, so maybe the whole thing wouldn't matter then. If you do decide to keep the `r'^'` in use, just keep in mind that it might cause conflicting problems with other urls, so be sure to always put it last.

Comment: hey @yuvi this solution works but the images not shown when i restart my PC,

Comment: Could you please help on this

Comment: Oh leave it now i fixed it

Comment: it was maybe because the image was being uploaded as temporary file because of the MEDIA_ROOT setting but now i changed it so it is working now, anyways thanx

Comment: yes, exactly. temporary files get deleted after a reboot (hence temporary). I thought maybe the images are *supposed* to be temporary, but wasn't sure, so I didn't mention it in the answer.